# Gradle doesn't find plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm and kotlin2js

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I'm a beginner in gradle, using version 4.8.

Whatever I do , the plugins are never found. I get this error message:

Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.3.20'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.3.20')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository

No matter how many repositories I add, it seems it is only looking in  "Gradle Central Plugin Repository"

My gradle.build file:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.20"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.20"

    }

}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.20'
    id 'kotlin2js' version '1.3.20'
}
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem because i forgot about proxy settings like `systemProp.https.proxyHost` and `systemProp.http.proxyHost` and etc. that was set in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`.

I fixed configuration and plugin was successfully dowlnloaded

Check `gradle.properties` and try to add correct proxy settings if you behind firewall or escape this settings if you not.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following `gradle.build` configuration:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.20"
    }

}

plugins {
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin2js'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

When you include the plugin by `id`, it seems Gradle wants to retrieve the plugin from the Gradle plugin portal, but the Kotlin plugin is not there, it's part of the buildscript dependency. Using it with the `apply plugin` works. You can also find a slightly different working example [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/javascript/getting-started-gradle/getting-started-with-gradle.html).

Answer (score 0):

you need to add repository `mavenCentral()` to the `buildscript` `dependencies`.

for example: [kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.20](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.20). also the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html) hints for that.

Comment: I try it , it did'nt work. I still only have     Gradle Central Plugin Repository as repository where it seems to search

Comment: @sab it's even in that repository: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.android ... while `org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.20` simply might not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project and then to the Gradle script. In Gradle, Go to Setting.Gradle and change the Fist Bitray Url to https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).